# WordPress docker container does not start with mysql:latest image

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I have setup wordpress with mariadb containers without any issues.

Now I am trying to test wordpress with mysql.

Commands used:

```
$ docker run --name mysql01 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password1234 -d mysql
$ docker run --name wordpress01 --link mysql01 -p 8080:80 -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql01:3306 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=Password1234 -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress -e WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_ -d wordpress
```

status of containers:

```
$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
e71299679e73        mysql               "docker-entrypoint..."   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql01

$ docker ps -a 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                 NAMES
c0a7dd46fb33        wordpress           "docker-entrypoint..."   5 minutes ago       Exited (1) 4 minutes ago                         wordpress01
e71299679e73        mysql               "docker-entrypoint..."   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes               3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql01
```

Error Logs:

```
$ docker logs wordpress01 
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in Standard input code on line 22

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in Standard input code on line 22

MySQL Connection Error: (2054) The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn't work by default with MySQL v8 yet as mentioned [here](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/313#issuecomment-401049241). Also, the example in `wordpress` docker image [readme](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) uses MySQL v5.7. Changing mysql version to 5.7 should do the job.

```
docker run --name mysql01 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password1234 -d mysql:5.7
```

If you need to use `mysql:latest` docker image, starting mysql with `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` argument should also work as mentioned [here](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/issues/313#issuecomment-400836783).

```
docker run --name mysql01 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Password1234 -d mysql --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Comment: same error with mysql:latest .. it does NOT work with the mentioned argument.  --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

Comment: Check if mysql container is successfully started by checking `docker logs -f mysql01`. If you start wordpress container immediately after starting mysql container, you might get connection refused errors since mysql takes some time to start. If you get that, try removing wordpress container using `docker rm -f wordpress01`, then start wordpress container again and then check `docker logs -f wordpress01`.